# Test accuracy of neural net is going up and down

Tags: neural-network, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I am using a CNN to classify medical images. I am using a four convolutional layers with ReLU activation followed by a softmax layer. I am using rmsprop as the optimizer. The problem I am facing is the network's test accuracy increases and then goes down. This continues till the maximum number of epochs is reached. I read somewhere that this could be due to the fact that the network shifts its weights in favor of one class, and then has to do so in favor of the other class. I shuffled the test data, to see if this would help, but no such luck. Is there any remedy?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the image you are sharing, the training accuracy continues to increase, the validation accuracy is changing around the 50%. I think either you do not have enough data to use neural network or the network is small to capture all the information, in both cases I feel there either under fitting or over fitting problem. Can you give us some information about the database so we can help more

Comment: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0137036. That is the network I am trying to implement. I have 100 MRI images. I have followed the same procedure as in the paper I have linked to. It is a very similar database.

Comment: 100 images is very few , you can not use DNN

Comment: Try to use hog or sift with sparse coding and svm

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself clearer. The MRI images have a varying number of slices. I extract these slices, and augment them by rotating them. This gives me around 10k 'images' to work with. The test set is around 1k slices, but it is heavily imbalanced.

Comment: What is the learning rate you are using?

Comment: I am using the default learning rate for sgd in Keras, which I think is 0.01. I have also reduced the learning rate. I didn't see much of an effect.

Comment: @HimanshuRai My test set is pretty imbalanced. Could this be a possible reason for the oscillatory behaviour?

Comment: Not really. If your training set is imbalanced that is a big problem, is that the case?

Comment: No, the training set is pretty well balanced. 4870 images in one class to 4260 in the other.

Comment: @BH85 Would the inclusion of more layers solve the problem, if it were an underfitting problem?

Comment: Yes it can if you believe that there is under fitting

Answer (score 0):

With the screenshot you shared, the difference between the training accuracy and the validation accuracy is huge. 90 to 50 is a big gap, which means your model is actually overfitting. It's learning to well from the training data, that it's unable to generalize it with real time or nevee seen data. My guess is the reason it's fluctuating is because of that. Try to increase your dataset, if it's an image classification, try image augmentations and try not to make the model too complex. I'm sure it'll help.